# Multiple Java instances -Bluemix + Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, ibm-cloud, saucelabs, browserstack

I have deployed a web based app on bluemix which would run selenium test cases when the url is triggered.

However I am facing issues when 2 users trigger trigger the tests at the same time as the 1st user's webdriver instance is still in use and I would have a complete copy instance to run when the second user tries to run the test simultaneously without aborting the 1ST User's test.

Comment: Either implement your webapp so it can serve more than one request at a time, or put in a check and reject additional requests while a long-running one is being served.